# UIButton stays highlighted until UITableView ends scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have my own custom navigation controller(that subclasses UIViewController) that has a stack for the view controllers. It has a custom navigation bar and a content view, where I add the view of the   view controller at the top of my stack of view controllers. 
Then navigation bar, which is a subclass of UIView, I didn't subclass UINavigationBar, because I don't need to, has a Back button, and another button which at this moment doesn't have any action connected.
My problem is that if I scroll a UITableView (that belongs to the current view controller on the stack) and I press either on my back button or on the other button, both of them stay highlighted until the UITableView ends scrolling. It's the weirdest behavior ever, and I don't understand why it happens. 
Any suggestions please?

Comment: Apparently, if I call [button setHighlighted:NO] on my IBAction it de-highlights it even if the UITableView is still scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, if I call [button setHighlighted:NO] on my IBAction it de-highlights it even if the UITableView is still scrolling